# JAVA: Sorting an array in descending order

Tags: java

I'm trying to sort an array in descending order, I know there are many examples of sorting an array online, but I just wanted to try and do it my own way (just trying to test to see if algorithm could actually work). But some reason, I'm unable to output the array with the result stored, I've tried using System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myList)); and printing them one at time, it works for one the arrays i created, but when trying to modify the array through a loop, it refused to output anything, no error, nothing as though nothing is there. Your help would be appreciated. see code below. Thanks.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class TestArray {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      double[] myList = {1.9, 2.9, 9.2, 3.4, 4.2, 6.7, 3.5};
      double[] sortedList = new double[7] ; 


      // Print all the array elements
      for (double i: myList) {
         System.out.println(i + " ");
      }

      // Summing all elements
      double total = 0;
      for (double x: myList) {
         total += x;
      }
      System.out.println("Total is " + total);

      // Finding the largest element
      double max = myList[0];
      int m, z = 0;

      for (double k: myList) {
         if (k > max) max = k;
      }

      do{
        for (int i = m; i < myList.length; i++) {
          if (myList[i] > max){      
             max = myList[i];  
             z = i;
          }
        }

        sortedList[m] = max;
        myList[z] =0;
        m++;

      } while(m < myList.length);

      System.out.println("Max is " + max);
      //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myList)); 
      for (double y: sortedList) {
         System.out.println(y + " ");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: It appears that you never assign anything to `sortedList`, other than possibly the first element.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen actually he seems to do that but it's hard to spot due to the poor intendation. I'll fix that :)

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for the edit :-)

Comment: Can you show us the code that causes the problem and what output you get and what you'd expect instead? I doubt "it refused to output anything" is accurate, either you didn't output anything or you got output that _you_ interpreted to be nothing but which is actually there. Besides that, did you step through your code with a debugger?

Answer (score 1):

**you can simply use inbuilt function to sort your array in descending order as**

```
Arrays.sort(myList , Collections.reverseOrder());

System.out.println("myList Array Elements in reverse order:");
    for (int i = 0; i < myList .length; i++)
       System.out.println(intArray[i]);
```

It will work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic for sorting is not working as intended. I have made some changes to it, give it a try :

```
    do {
           max = 0;
           for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
               if (myList[i] > max) {
                   max = myList[i];
                   z = i;
               }
           }

           sortedList[m] = max;
           myList[z] = 0;
           m++;

   } while (m < myList.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert this line `int m, z = 0;` to `int m = 0, z = 0;`
because `int m, z = 0;` is equivalent to `int m; int z = 0;`. Hence when you try to use variable `m` - it is not initialized yet and that results to a compilation error. 
After fixing the above statement, your program will compile and run but there is also a mistake in the program logic as well and your result sorted array will be output as:

`{9.2, 9.2, 9.2, 9.2, 9.2, 9.2, 9.2}`

as in the following block

`for (double k: myList) {
    if (k > max) max = k;
}`

you initially find the max value which is 9.2 . That's why when you later execute `do .. while` and check the condition here

`if (myList[i] > max){
    max = myList[i];
    z = i;
}`

the statement `myList[i] > max` will never return `true` and hence your `max` will be always remain 9.2 and `z` will be always remain `0`. That's why the line `sortedList[m] = max;` always inserts 9.2 to each index of your sorted array.

In such cases i recommend you to use an IDE of your choice(Intellij Idea, Eclipse, etc.) which will highlight compilation errors and help you to find your bugs using the integrated debugger.

So i just found your mistakes, i think now you can manage it. In case of additional help feel free to communicate.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] myList = {1.9, 2.9, 9.2, 3.4, 4.2, 6.7, 3.5};
    double[] sortedList = new double[7] ;


    // Print all the array elements
    for (double i: myList) {
        System.out.println(i + " ");
    }

    // Summing all elements
    double total = 0;
    for (double x: myList) {
        total += x;
    }
    System.out.println("Total is " + total);

    // Finding the largest element
    double max = myList[0];
    int m = 0;
    int z = 0;

    do{
        for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
            if (myList[i] > max){
                max = myList[i];
                z = i;
            }
        }

        sortedList[m] = max;
        myList[z] =0;
        m++;
        max = 0;

    } while(m < myList.length);

    System.out.println("Max is " + max);
    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myList));
    for (double y: sortedList) {
        System.out.println(y + " ");
    }
}
}
```

You're code contained three errors:

1.You failed to reset 'max' in every iteration, leading to 'sortedList'
containing just the value 9.2 in every entry.

2. ```
   for (double k: myList) {
    if (k > max) max = k;
   }
   ```

   is unneccessary. Moreover, it doesn't even keep track where the max element is.

3.

```
for (int i = m; i < myList.length; i++)
```

should be changed to

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++)
```

The position you're at in 'sortedList' has nothing to do with where you can
find the maximum element of 'myList'.